# Xcode force enable application rotation

Tags: ipad, rotation

I am working on an iPad/iPhone tab-bar based application. I have about 30 class files and need to enable rotation in the app, so that iPad users can view at any orientation. As far as I know, every class needs rotation to be enabled by using the following:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}
```

However, I have some `UIViewControllers` created and displayed completely in a single class file, and as far as I know you cannot enable it for that type.
Is there a way I can enable global rotation for the app? I have tried in Info.plist. is there something that can be added to the `AppDelegate` to enable global rotation?
Btw: I have already tried adding returning `YES` for rotation in every class file.
Thanks in advance,
Baharini

Answer (score 0):

In `Xcode` on the `Project Navigator` click on the project name. Now on center view on the `Summary` tab, you can see the `iPad\iPhone Development Info` in this part there is `Supported Device Orientations`. You can set all of them for supporting any orientation!

I hope it be useful for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I do not understand what you mean by iPad/iPhone development info and the Summer of project. Are you referring to the Xcode project or a book? I really do not understand Summer. Also, in Xcode I set the interface orientations and it had no effect on the app. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm so sorry! I spelled check.